# How to grant permission to user to create packages in IBM Cloud DB2? I don't know the DBA User

Tags: coldfusion, db2

I am unable to connect with ColdFusion, and getting following error.

```
Connection verification failed for data source: DB2Test
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][DB2 JDBC Driver]Bind process is not active. Please ensure that the user has permissions to create packages. Packages cannot be created in an XA Connection.
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][DB2 JDBC Driver]Bind process is not active. Please ensure that the user has permissions to create packages. Packages cannot be created in an XA Connection.
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you on?

Comment: What did the dba say when you presented this problem to him or her?

Comment: What @DanBracuk said. This is not something you can solve strictly w/ CF. It's a permission issue with the DB user itself.

Comment: I was using free DB2 account in IBM cloud, they don't allow to create packages for free account users, they said I need to buy Enterprise to develop my test application.